# KIE features in Fuse 7

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, karaf, fuseesb

I'm upgrading to Fuse 7, and having some trouble updating our rule engine to work in OSGi.

My jar can't find these libs in Karaf:

```
    org.kie.api;version="[7.11,8)",
    org.kie.api.event.rule;version="[7.11,8)",
    org.kie.api.runtime;version="[7.11,8)",
    org.kie.api.runtime.rule;version="[7.11,8)",
```

I was searching for a features list that can be installed, and best I found was [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-osgi/kie-karaf-features/src/main/filtered-resources/repository/features-fuse.xml):

```
features:addurl mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features-core
```

This added the following installable features:

```
hibernate-validator                     
hibernate-validator-paranamer           
drools-common                           
drools-decisiontable                    
drools-wb-guided-decisiontables         
kie-dmn                                 
jbpm-commons                            
jbpm-human-task                         
jbpm                                    
optaplanner-engine                      
droolsjbpm-hibernate                    
h2                                      
kie-server-client                       
servlet-api-kie                         
kie-pmml                                
jpa
```

But none of these look like they have org.kie.api libraries.

Anyone have an idea how to get kie-osgi libs installed on Fuse?  Thanks

Comment: Please check https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/kie-karaf-features-7.11.0.Final-features-core.xml - there's `kie` feature that should provide what you need.

Comment: Ah thank you, that worked.